# CUBA-Platform + EmailInfo - How to specify FTL template path under WEB-INF?

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I have `email.ftl` under modules/portal/web/WEB-INF/templates/email/ (a subfolder I created). In my controller code, I have my EmailInfo declaration, and I want to specify the path to email.ftl.

Looking at [this tutorial](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.4/sending_emails_recipe.html), I see the EmailInfo declaration is this:

```
EmailInfo emailInfo = new EmailInfo(
            "john.doe@company.com,jane.roe@company.com", 
            newsItem.getCaption(),
            null,
            "com/company/demo/templates/news_item.txt",
            Collections.singletonMap("newsItem", newsItem)
    );
```

I notice the relative path leading to news_item.txt starts from `com/` which leads me to believe that the root of the path starts from the "src" folder of the module the controller is in (my controller is in app-portal, so in my case, `portal/src`). Since my template is under `web/` and not `src/`, I specified my path as so:

```
EmailInfo emailInfo = new EmailInfo("email@email.com", "Email Template", null, "../web/WEB-INF/templates/email/email.ftl", null, null);[/pre]
```

However, it didn't work, as an error was thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find template by path: ../web/WEB-INF/templates/email/email.ftl

So my question is, how to specify this file path to go under a different subfolder, specifically "modules/portal/web"?

Thanks, Mingle

==X-posted from CUBA-Platform forum==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yuriy Artamonov on CUBA-Platform for answering:

> Unfortunately, you cannot store email templates in portal / web modules, since they are processed on a middleware. I recommend that you put them into core module src folder. In fact, "/" means CLASS-PATH root, not the folder.
>
> Templates are loaded by Emailer using Resources interface which loads resources
> using the following rules: https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.5/resources.html

I put `email.ftl` under `modules/core/src/com/example/test/email/email.ftl` and specified the path of `/com/example/test/email/email.ftl` and it worked.